# Why don't .not() have any affect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```js
$('body').not('.specific_element').css('opacity','.3');
```

```css
body{
  border: 1px solid;
}
.specific_element{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>There are some texts</p>
<div class="specific_element">
  sth
</div>
<p>whatever</p>
```

All I'm trying to do is keeping the opacity of the element that has a red border to `1`. I mean I want to apply `opacity: .3` on everything except that specific element. How can I do that?

Comment: the specific element is inside the body and you applied opacity on the body. so all inside the body will have opacity even if you exclude one element because that element is still inside the body

Comment: @guradio Well what is the job of `.not()` there?

Comment: so all inside the body will have opacity even if you exclude one element because that element is still inside the body

Comment: @guradio Ah I see. Don't you know any trick to handle that?

Comment: apply opacity on sibling of the excluded element not on the container

Comment: @stack .`specific_element` is inner_element of the body .That's why is it have opacity.but css not really `0.3`  `console.log($('.specific_element').css('opacity'))
console.log($('body').css('opacity'))`  .you can see the difference

Comment: @stack use `rgba`

Comment: That's how it works. `.not` filters out current jQuery elements. Since `body` has no `specific_element`, it has no effect on it.

Comment: @Mr.Alien What you mean exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Apply the opacity on the children of the container with the exception of the specific element

```js
$('body').children().not('.specific_element').css('opacity','.3');
```

```css
body{
  border: 1px solid;
}

.specific_element{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>There are some texts</p>
<div class="specific_element">
  sth
</div>
<p>whatever</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Select all elements inside body except '.specific_element'
$('body *').not('.specific_element').css('opacity','.3');
```

Comment: I'd suggest `$('body>*')` - because otherwise, two levels down the effective opacity would be 0.09, three levels down 0.027, then 0.0081 etc

Answer (score 1):

```
$('*:not(*[class*="specific_element"])').css('opacity','.3');
```

> on **everything** except that specific element.

Use * to select **everything**

Answer (score 0):

As @guradio suggested, it would be done by applying opacity on sibling of the specific element:

```js
$('.specific_element').siblings().css('opacity','.3');
```

```css
body{
  border: 1px solid;
}

.specific_element{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>There are some texts</p>
<div class="specific_element">
  sth
</div>
<p>whatever</p>
```